# Mysql Error #1064

Tags: mysql, sql

Error

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE RscCompView(
RscCompViewID int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
RscCompID int( 11 ) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL ,
req_dateTIMESTAMP( 14 ) ,
PRIMARY KEY ( RscCompViewID ) ,
KEY req_date( req_date ) ,
KEY RscCompID( RscCompID )
);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14),
>     PRIMARY KEY (RscCompViewID),
>     KEY req_date (req_date),
>     KEY RscCompID ' at line 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Timestamp` data type cannot have length, the length should be removed and it will work,

```
CREATE TABLE RscCompView
(
    RscCompViewID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    RscCompID int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL ,
    req_date TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (RscCompViewID) ,
    KEY req_date (req_date) ,
    KEY RscCompID (RscCompID)
);
```

For additional information, the data type `INT(11)` doesn't mean that the length for integer is 11 but it is how the integer value will be padded with zero on the left if `ZEROFILL` is also specified. The range value of *signed integer* is `-2147483648 to 2147483647` while the *unsigned integer* is `0 to   4294967295`.

Consider the following example,

```
INT(3)      INT(3) ZEROFILL
1           001
10          010
100         100
```

Comment: Thanks JW its Done!! Great help my dear Thanks again!!!